# Customize background image on BlackBerry field or manager

Tags: java, blackberry

How do I draw a background image with round corners and a shadow on a BlackBerry?

Comment: Which version of the Blackberry OS are you targeting?

Answer (score 0):

BB 4.5 version? I use Background but it runs last on 4.6...